# SQLite - Could not open database file

Tags: android, exception, sqlite, xamarin, android-sqlite

I am coding a Xamarin Android application, and am getting an error when trying to create a SQLite database.

Here is my code:

```
string applicationFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "CanFindLocation");
string databaseFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(applicationFolderPath, "CanFindLocation.db");
SQLite.SQLite3.Config(SQLite.SQLite3.ConfigOption.Serialized);
var db = new SQLiteConnection (databaseFileName);
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
SQLite.SQLiteException: Could not open database file: /data/data/com.xamarin.docs.android.mapsandlocationdemo2/files/CanFindLocation/CanFindLocation.db (CannotOpen)
```

I have the same code working in another Xamarin application and would like to know if the exception has something to do with the name of the package?

Thanks in advance

Comment: click your database visible top right menu Sql lite Browser select it

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Does the path folder path that you are providing to SQLite exist? If you haven't created the `CanFindLocation` folder then opening a connection to that path will fail.

Try:

```
string applicationFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "CanFindLocation");

// Create the folder path.
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(applicationFolderPath);

string databaseFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(applicationFolderPath, "CanFindLocation.db");
SQLite.SQLite3.Config(SQLite.SQLite3.ConfigOption.Serialized);
var db = new SQLiteConnection (databaseFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks, wish I could upvote several times, took hours to find this post!

Comment: I am getting the same error, ...
But SQLite.SQLite3 doesnt have "Config" method, why?
I am using "sqlite-net-pcl (1.4.118)" and "Xamarin.Forms(3.1.0)"

Comment: I found that whilst debugging sometimes, the Path magically doesn't exist, then I run again and it works. on and off

Comment: Hilariously, I've just re-discovered this via Google and solved my own issue with my own answer without realising initially... Doh!

Answer (score 1):

My problem is related to added the option of "SQLiteOpenFlags.Create" during the initialization.

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using MAUI, I was able to get past the same error but setting path to

```
System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
```